# Value on JSF page doesn't update even if the getter method is correct

Tags: javascript, jsf, jsf-2, navigation, backing-beans

On a JSF page (lets say page1) I click a link that triggers a pop up through JavaScript. The pop up appears and the JSF page1 stays in the background.

In the pop up I work also work JSF. When I`m finished with the pop up I click on a button on the pop up that calls a window.close() JavaScript function to close it and the action method of the button updates the values in the managing bean of the same page1 and returns the path of the page page1 to redirect me to the same place that I started the pop up. So the getter method gets the good value, but my page1 doesn't get updated, just after a manual refresh.

Both beans (the "caller" pop up bean and the "receiver" bean) are SessionScoped.

**EDIT**

- page1 == tests.xhtml
- the backing bean of tests.xhtml is TestsBean
- I click on one of the links with the value="Test no. #{o.noGrid}
- the onclick attribute triggers the JavaScript script that brings the pop up
- snippet of the xhtml

  ```
     <tbody>
                          <ui:repeat var="o" value="#{testsBean.gridTableGeneral}"
                              varStatus="status">
                              <h:form>
                                  <h:panelGroup rendered="#{status.even}">
                                      <tr>
                                          <td class="order-table-even-row"><h:commandLink
                                                  action="#{gridPopUpBean.showGridTest()}" target="_blank"
                                                  onclick="confirmGrid('Are you sure you want to start the test no. #{o.noGrid}?');"
                                                  value="Test no. #{o.noGrid}">
                                                  <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{o.noGrid}"
                                                      target="#{testsBean.noGridToShow}" />
                                              </h:commandLink></td>
                                          <td class="order-table-even-row">#{o.totalAccess}</td>
                                          <td class="order-table-even-row">#{o.maxPercentage} %</td>
                                          <td class="order-table-even-row"><h:commandLink
                                                  action="#{testsBean.showGridDetaildPage()}">
                                                  <img src="/juritest/resources/img/details.png"
                                                      alt="details" />
                                              </h:commandLink></td>
                                      </tr>
                                  </h:panelGroup>
                                  <h:panelGroup rendered="#{status.odd}">
                                      <tr>
                                          <td class="order-table-odd-row"><h:commandLink
                                                  action="#{gridPopUpBean.showGridTest()}" target="_blank"
                                                  onclick="confirmGrid('Are you sure you want to start the test no. #{o.noGrid}?');"
                                                  value="Test no. #{o.noGrid}">
                                                  <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{o.noGrid}"
                                                      target="#{testsBean.noGridToShow}" />
                                              </h:commandLink></td>
                                          <td class="order-table-odd-row">#{o.totalAccess}</td>
                                          <td class="order-table-odd-row">#{o.maxPercentage} %</td>
                                          <td class="order-table-odd-row"><h:commandLink
                                                  action="#{testsBean.showGridDetaildPage()}">
                                                  <img src="/juritest/resources/img/details.png"
                                                      alt="details" />
                                              </h:commandLink></td>
                                      </tr>
                                  </h:panelGroup>
                              </h:form>
                          </ui:repeat>
  ```
- and snippets of the the backing bean TestBean.java of this page is

  ```
         @ManagedBean
         @SessionScoped
         public class TestsBean implements Serializable {

     private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

         @EJB
     TestsManager testsManager;

     @ManagedProperty(value = "#{applicationContainer}")
     private ApplicationContainer container;

     @ManagedProperty(value = "#{accessesBean}")
     private AccessesBean accessesBean;

         ...
         getters / setter for the ui:repeat

         ...

    public void extractInformationFromDB(int gridCategory) {

  // extract from the container the right category grids
  gridList = testsManager.extractFromContainerRightCategory(container, gridCategory);
  // extract from the right grids array list the grid numbers
  setNoGrid(testsManager.setNoGrid(gridList));

  // extract the accesses
  accessList = accessesBean.getAccessInformation(gridCategory);
  // extract from the access array list the grid numbers
  setNoAccessGrid(accessesBean.setNoAccessGrid(accessList));

  setGridTableGeneral(testsManager.createGridTableGeneral(gridList,
          getNoGrid(), accessList, getNoAccessGrid()));
  ```

  }
- the pop up after it done it's job ends up with the answerResult.xhtml

  ```
        <ui:repeat var="n"
                  value="#{answerResultBean.accessWrongAnswerColumnWrapperList}">
                  <hr />
                  <h:outputText value="#{n.noQuestion}. #{n.question}" />
                  <table style="text-align: left;">
                      <tr>
                          <td>
                              <h:form>
                                  <h:graphicImage
                                      value="/resources/img/#{n.rightGridAnswerA ? 'tick' : 'x'}Small.png"
                                      alt="#{n.rightGridAnswerA ? 'right' : 'wrong'} " />
                              </h:form></td>
                          <td>
                              <h:outputText value="a) #{n.a}"
                                  style="#{n.userAnswerA ? 'font-weight:bold;' : 'font-weight:normal;'}" />
                          </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>
                              <h:form>
                                  <h:graphicImage
                                      value="/resources/img/#{n.rightGridAnswerB ? 'tick' : 'x'}Small.png"
                                      alt="#{n.rightGridAnswerB ? 'right' : 'wrong'} " />
                              </h:form></td>
                          <td>
                              <h:outputText value="b) #{n.b}"
                                  style="#{n.userAnswerB ? 'font-weight:bold;' : 'font-weight:normal;'}" />
                          </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>
                              <h:form>
                                  <h:graphicImage
                                      value="/resources/img/#{n.rightGridAnswerC ? 'tick' : 'x'}Small.png"
                                      alt="#{n.rightGridAnswerC ? 'right' : 'wrong'} " />
                              </h:form></td>
                          <td>
                              <h:outputText value="c) #{n.c}"
                                  style="#{n.userAnswerC ? 'font-weight:bold;' : 'font-weight:normal;'}" />
                          </td>
                      </tr>
                  </table>
                  <hr />
              </ui:repeat>
          </div>
          <div id="loginDiv">
              <h:commandButton style="text-align:left"
                  onclick="closeWindow(); return true;"
                  action="#{answerResultBean.closeButton()}" value="Close" />
          </div>
  ```
- and the backing bean of this final page of the pop up is AnswerResult.java

  ```
   @ManagedBean
   @SessionScoped
   public class AnswerResultBean implements Serializable {

      private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @ManagedProperty(value = "#{testsBean}")
  private TestsBean testsBean;

      private AccessAnswerResultWrapper accessAnswerResultWrapper;
  private ArrayList<AccessWrongAnswerColumnWrapper> accessWrongAnswerColumnWrapperList;

  // getter / setter START

  /**
   * @param testsBean The testsBean to set.
   */
  public void setTestsBean(TestsBean testsBean) {
  this.testsBean = testsBean;
   }
  ```

  ...

  ```
    public String closeButton() {

  testsBean.extractInformationFromDB(GridHelper.convertingGridCategoryFromStringToInteger(getAccessAnswerResultWrapper().getCategory()));
  return Utils.path + "/tests/tests";
  ```

  }
- I click the button on the pop up with the value="Close" trigger and event that closes the pop up, after that the method closeButton() gets executed, the extraction method from the TestBean.java gets executed, which inside of it sets the attribute which I use as an attribute in the ui:repeat in the tests.xhtml and finally the action method closeButton() redirect me to the tests.xhtml, which in turn calls the backing bean again TestBean.java.

I know it a mess, I know it is not DRY and the design is faulty, but I am in continuos learning.

In the final stage I redirect to tests.xhtml, before I set the attribute it uses, the tests.xhtml call the bean and it SHOULD be updated with the new values. But it doesn't get updated, just after a manual refresh.

Comment: Any ideas on what happens ?

Comment: You'll probably get decent suggestions when you post some code. Before that, what you'll get are guesses.

Comment: To update the tests.xhtml after the pop up closes. See edits.

Comment: In debug when it calls the TestBean backing bean and calls the getter of the attribute. The attribute is the good, with the values updated, but the page tests.xhtml shows the previous attribute. Just after a manual refresh the attribute is the same and in the page it shows

Comment: Refresh programmatically the page...I don't know what to do. I have to change something or add something. I am a newbie compared to you guys :)